# send index path of tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, popup

I have an image in my tableViewCell and when I click it I have a popup that appears (another UIView). I would like for when I click the image on my tableviewcell for the image to be passed on to the popup. Here is how I set up the popup.

```
  @IBAction func PopUpClicked(_ sender: Any) -> Void {
            self.transparentBackground = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.transparentBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.8)
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.addSubview(self.transparentBackground)
            self.opaqueView = self.setupOpaqueView()
            self.transparentBackground.addSubview(opaqueView)
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bringSubview(toFront: self.transparentBackground)
            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: transparentBackground)

    }

 func setupOpaqueView() -> UIView{


        let mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 132, width: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width-32), height: 403))
        mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.23, green:0.73, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
        mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 6


        let  OKbutton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 151, y: Int(mainView.frame.height-60), width: 40, height: 40))
        OKbutton.setImage( UIImage.init(named: "AddOn"), for: .normal)
        OKbutton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        OKbutton.layer.borderWidth = 2
        OKbutton.layer.cornerRadius = 20



        self.imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 29, y: 18, width: 274, height: 310))
        self.imageView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor


        mainView.addSubview(OKbutton)
        mainView.addSubview(self.imageView)
        OKbutton.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(ThirdWheelViewController.handleOKButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return mainView

    }

    func handleOKButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
        removeAnimate()

    }

    func removeAnimate()
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.transparentBackground.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.transparentBackground.alpha = 0.0;

        }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
            if (finished)
            {
                self.transparentBackground.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Cant you just assign `self.imageView.image = cellImageView.image` where `cellImageView` is the image view in your cell?

Answer (score 0):

in cellForItemAtIndexPath add target to your item and tag for it

send the index in the item tag

some thing like that

```
 let cell: CcImageGallery = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CcImageGallery", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CcImageGallery


    cell.btnShape.setImage(UIImage(named: shapeImg[indexPath.row] as! String), forState: .Normal)
    cell.btnShapeText.setTitle(shapeTxt[indexPath.row] as? String, forState: .Normal)

    cell.btnShapeRadio.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(selectImage(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.btnShapeRadio.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.btnShape.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(selectImage(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.btnShape.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.btnShapeText.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(selectImage(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.btnShapeText.tag = indexPath.row


    return cell
```

Comment: sorry I didn't mention I already have that  `cell.PopUp.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PopUpClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        cell.PopUp.tag = indexPath.row
        print(indexPath.row)
        cell.PopUp.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
`

Comment: I am trying to send an image when I click the cell to the popup view

Comment: Well sorry when I click a button which os popupclicked, I want to pass the image in the cell I clicked

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRow` function, add image click listener in this way

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Then, get the image that is clicked on in this way

```
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView

    // Your action
}
```

Finally, you don't want this image until the user click on another button. So what you need is not passing images. You just need to store the image in memory and let your button click read from it. So you define the `imageTapped` function in this way

```
var tappedImage: UIImage?
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
}
```

Then when user clicks on `PopUpClicked` function where you create your `UIView` using `self.opaqueView = self.setupOpaqueView()`, read from this stored image variable in your `setupOpaqueView()` function

```
func setupOpaqueView() -> UIView{
    // methods....
    self.imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 29, y: 18, width: 274, height: 310))
    self.imageView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    // add the stored image in this way
    if let tappedImage = self.tappedImage {
        self.imageView.image = tappedImage
    }
    // methods...

}
```

Comment: sorry i don't think my question is clear enough, how do I actually send it, I am familar with sending information through an override segue but there is no segue here. You call the destination controller and pass the information. I don't know how to call the destination controller when there isn't a segue

Comment: @juelizabeth From this `imageTapped` function, where are you sending your image to? Are you going to present a `UIView` in the same view controller and pass the image to that `UIView`?

Comment: yes that is what I am doing. You can see i am calling a new view in the code in my question

Comment: @juelizabeth Then why can't you call your `setupOpaqueView()` in `imageTapped` function to create the view and then assign the image?

Comment: please can you edit the code to show me how I would do that?

Comment: @juelizabeth Sure but one last question, so you want to show the view when click on another button, not when you click on the imageView, right?